# Yeoman throwed error SAP UI5 Application Generator on vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, sapui5, sap-fiori, sap-gateway, ui5-tooling

I get the error message that creating the Fiori App which source Odata.

```
{"message":"@sap/fiori:app generator failed - env.on(error) Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'version')","stack":"TypeError: env.on(error) Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'version')\n\tat default_1._applyDefaults (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/@sap/generator-fiori/generators/app-gen-shared/app/index.js:1:676600)\n\tat default_1.writing (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/@sap/generator-fiori/generators/app-gen-shared/app/index.js:1:673522)\n\tat Object.<anonymous> (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/@sap/generator-fiori/generators/commonlibs/index.js:2:4454280)\n\tat /opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/@sap/generator-fiori/generators/commonlibs/index.js:2:3726211\n\tat new Promise (<anonymous>)\n\tat /opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/@sap/generator-fiori/generators/commonlibs/index.js:2:3725971\n\tat g.add.once (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/@sap/generator-fiori/generators/commonlibs/index.js:2:4454298)\n\tat Immediate.<anonymous> (/Users/mert/.vscode/extensions/sapos.yeoman-ui-1.13.0/dist/extension.js:2:1970918)\n\tat process.processImmediate (node:internal/timers:466:21)"}
```

[image: 1.]
[image]

I found some solution up about this error that relates certification or proxy settings   but it didn't work for me.

I'm using MacOS system, If I call OData URL on Firefox It gets the Data XML correctly. At this time, I tried the Safari Browser with same URL then it explode pop-up which is contain about ask opening Outlook I didn't understand about topic.

Is there anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it.

---

As you can see, I've already connected the SAP System I get data. So, I should have to choose 'Connect to a System' which is Data Source that for reading services automatically.

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).